# boost::this_thread::disable_interruption usage confusion

Tags: c++, linux, boost, multithreading

boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp contains this code:

```
...
#include <boost/thread/detail/thread_interruption.hpp>
...

class shared_mutex
{
    ...
    void lock_shared()
    {
        boost::this_thread::disable_interruption do_not_disturb;
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(state_change);

        while(state.exclusive || state.exclusive_waiting_blocked)
        {
            shared_cond.wait(lk);
        }
        ++state.shared_count;
    }
    ...
};
```

but boost/thread/detail/thread_interruption.hpp does not contain implementation of disable_interruption, only the prototype.

in boost_1_42_0/libs/thread/src/pthread we don't have the implementation too

how does it work!???

Answer (score 1):

`grep` finds it in `boost_1_42_0/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp`:

```
    disable_interruption::disable_interruption():
        interruption_was_enabled(interruption_enabled())
    {
        if(interruption_was_enabled)
        {
            detail::get_current_thread_data()->interrupt_enabled=false;
        }
    }
```

Destructor and methods are all there too.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 implementations of `disable_interruption`.

1. `boost_1_42_0/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp`
2. `boost_1_42_0/libs/thread/src/win32/thread.cpp`

You link against the appropriate one depending on your platform